# Prevent the text included in tables included in the word count

Tags: tables, word-count

Is there a way to prevent the text included in tables be counted in the PDF created using latex?

I am submitting a paper to a journal and they are counting the text which is included in the table via the tool they are using (which should not happen as they add 200 words to each table and figure). And this results in exceeding the word limit.

So my only option is to prevent the text be counted in tables (without making them images)
Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they just assuming that each figure and table is equivalent to 200 words while ignoring any content in the figures/tables? Figures can take space with no internal words.

Comment: Typically publishers are not interested in the word count as such, but rather in the amount of pages required to print the submission. Can you give the number of pages to them?